# Is there hooks for native mongodb driver for node like in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, microservices, domain-driven-design, messagebroker

**`Context: DDD project deployed as distributed event-based micro-services (also uses Onion architecture)`**

For saving data into persistence (mongodb), I am using native mongodb node.js driver (for some reasons not using ORM). I need to implement some kind of hooks to listen changes in data (entities) in db like user created, updated, basically CRUD. mongoose provides this kind of hooks, but I am not using mongoose as I mentioned earlier. I heard about new `Change Streams` feature in MongoDB (though only supported in replica-set/sharded deployments), and want to utilize this for implementing `hooks`.

Is there anyone used Change Streams for similar reasons, have any experience, any open-source library, etc would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look at this - https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/nodejs-change-streams-triggers/ This is basically what you should want to do.

Comment: @Yogesh_D thank you for the direction, I already watched this series and it is a good resource, however, I would be more interested in more streamlined solutions like some open source library which provides hooks as abstractions so that I can just declare what I wanted to do instead of directly using raw API